# activityForResult() returning nothing. Sending from Fragment; returning in parent Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

In a `Fragment`:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CheckInActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("---", ---); // several more edited out
    startActivityForResult(i, 98);
```

in a `onPostExecute()` in a `task` in `CheckInActivity();`

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
setResult(98, intent);
```

My entire `onActivityResult` in the parent `Activity` of the calling `Fragment`:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Add Location  <- this one works in other part of my code
        if (resultCode == 99 ) {
            mLocationClient.connect();
        }

        // Abandon <--- this one is broken
        if (resultCode == 98) {
            mLocationClient.connect();
        }

        switch (requestCode) {
        case CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST:

            switch (resultCode) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                /*
                 * Try the request again
                 */
                break;

            }
        }

    }
```

When I log out anything from the result method, i get nothing.  Not null, it just doesn't reach the code.

Can anyone see what is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried adding an `onActivityResult()` to the Fragment?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `startActivityForResult()` to start the parent `Activity`. **The callback for the result is the `OnActivityResult()` method in the `Fragment`, not the one in the activity.**

Implement `OnActivityResult()` in your `Fragment`. This is where the result will come in.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the requestCode for 98, not resultCode. If it still doesn't work try the same but with starting the activity from your fragment with getActivity().startActivityForResult()